# Word 2016: How do I find and replace all paragraph marks only in tables?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a 300+ page Word 2016 doc imported from another program that has a huge amount of tables. In every table cell there is at least one paragraph mark. I want to Find and Replace every single paragraph mark with nothing, but only in tables (there are tons of other paragraph marks in normal text that I want to leave alone).

I can use the Find/Replace dialog to do it manually, but that will take a huge amount of clicks and time. There is no "only in tables" option in the dialog box, so it seems I need to craft a VBA macro but I've never done that before. Below is the macro produced by recording the action of "Find/Replace a paragraph mark in one table". What needs to be changed to enable this to tackle all the tables at once?

```
Dim mytable As Table
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

For Each mytable In ActiveDocument.Tables
mytable.Range.Editors.Add wdEditorEveryone
Next
ActiveDocument.SelectAllEditableRanges (wdEditorEveryone)
ActiveDocument.DeleteAllEditableRanges (wdEditorEveryone)
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
Sub FindReplaceInTable()
'
' FindReplaceInTable Macro
'
'
    Selection.Tables(1).Select
    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "^p"
        .Replacement.Text = ""
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindAsk
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchKashida = False
        .MatchDiacritics = False
        .MatchAlefHamza = False
        .MatchControl = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute
End Sub
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
Sub ClearTblParaBreaks()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim Tbl As Table
For Each Tbl In ActiveDocument.Tables
  With Tbl.Range.Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Format = False
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindStop
    .MatchWildcards = True
    .Text = "[^13]{1,}"
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
  End With
Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```